# MySQL Left Join is reduing the number of rows being selected

Tags: mysql, left-join

Using MySQL 5.7 I am trying to pull a complete list of stores and dates, then join that list to another table that holds what items were sold on a particular day, with one row per item. My query is like so:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT store_number)
FROM (select date from date_table where date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31') as dates
CROSS JOIN (select store_number from store_number group by store_number) as stores
LEFT JOIN item_table as items
    ON stores.store_number = items.store_number
    AND dates.date = items.date
    AND items.item_number IN (1, 2, 3)
```

When I run COUNT(DISTINCT store_number) using just the dates and stores subquery I get 264 rows returned, one row for each store. This number is correct. When I run the above code including the LEFT JOIN to the item_table I only get 262, which leads me to believe that two stores did not sell those item_number values in the given date range. When I run the above code but I comment out the item_number IN (1, 2, 3) JOIN criteria I get 263 rows, which leads me to believe that one store did not sell any item_numbers in a given date range.

What I want is for each store and each date to be included no matter what, but just pull NULL column values wherever they do not have the appropriate data.

Originally I had the item_number filter in the WHERE clause, but that was having the same effect of reducing the stores returned. I then moved the filter to the LEFT JOIN clause expecting that to resolve the issue but it did not.

Comment: Can you provide full table definition with full datasets? It would be helpful for us to simulate your query! Eg: SHOW CREATE TABLE (EachOfYourTableName) would be ok!

Comment: @SeanAnglim This was the issue. I was pulling the COUNT DISTINCT to make sure all stores were getting pulled, but I was only checking the data table store_numbers which is why two were missing.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Comments are for asking for clarification or suggetions to the poster or problems. If you got an answer you can click to accept it to show it was most helpful. You can post an answer yourself. [Help]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that `store_number` is a column in multiple tables and your `COUNT(DISTINCT store_number)` doesn't specify which one to use. Based on your debugging, it looks like `items.store_number` is being used instead of `stores.store_number`.

To fix this, modify your COUNT DISTINCT query to ensure the `store_number` from the `stores` table is used:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT stores.store_number)
```